# What is the 16 in (chainId, 16) in an Eth smart contract that is on the Rinkeby network

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, smartcontracts

I am new to smart contracts and I am working on an Eth Rinkeby dapp and was wondering if anyone can tell me what the "16" means in this section:

}

```
    network = await getChain(parseInt(chainId, 16));
    this.setState({
      network: network.network,
      loading: false,
      onlyNetwork: false,
    });
  });
}
```

I know what chainID is but 16 doesn't belong to the Rinkeby network from what I can tell.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: As that number is being used as one of the parameters to `parseInt`, I'd guess that it's the number base, meaning that it should be looking for a base-16 (hex) value.

Answer (score 1):

Ken White's comment is correct.

`parseInt` is a built-in JavaScript function. The first parameter is the number. In the case of Rinkeby, this chainId is `4` (`4` in hexadecimal). The second parameter is the base. For hexadecimal, this is `16`.

As it happens, the decimal and hexadecimal numbers are the same. But, for example, if you were using the xDAI mainnet, the chainId in decimal is `100`, but in hexadecimal (which is what chain IDs are usually represented in), it's `64`.

`parseInt` needs to know the base in order to correctly convert the string containing the chain ID to the correct number. If the chainId string starts with `0x` (e.g. `0x64`), then `parseInt` can correctly tell what the base is (`16`). However, this is not always the case, so `16` is manually passed in to ensure that the correct base is used.

Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp